Efficiently recalculating dependent values in real-time data streams using NumPy in Python
I'm currently working on a real-time data processing system for financial securities, where I need to perform calculations as soon as new data comes in. Each financial security has multiple data points (about 10-20) being fed into the system in real-time, and I have around 200 different securities.
I am using a NumPy array to store this data, where each row represents a security and each column represents a different data point or calculated value. Whenever a new data point arrives, I need to recalculate several dependent values immediately.
Current Approach:
Currently, I have implemented this using Python functions associated with each column in the NumPy array. Here’s a simplified version of how my system works:

Data Feeding: New data for a security is fed into the corresponding row of the NumPy array.
Function Association: I have functions associated with each column. If a data point that a function depends on changes, the function is added to a list for that specific row.
Recalculation: After updating the NumPy array, I loop through the list of functions for each row and recalculate the dependent values.

Example:
Here is a dummy table to illustrate the concept:



Security
Price
Volume
Moving Average
Volatility




A
100
1000
102
0.02


B
150
2000
148
0.03


...
...
...
...
...




Price and Volume are real-time data points.
Moving Average and Volatility are calculated values that depend on the Price.

Example formulas:

Moving Average might be calculated as the average of the last 10 prices.
Volatility might be calculated as the standard deviation of the last 10 prices.

When the Price for Security A changes, both the Moving Average and Volatility need to be recalculated.
My Questions:

Is this approach of using functions and maintaining a list of recalculations for each row an efficient way to handle this problem?
I am concerned about the performance implications as the number of securities and data points increases. Specifically, I wonder if looping through functions for each update is optimal.

How do systems like Excel handle recalculations of dependent cells?
Excel seems to handle recalculations efficiently, even with large datasets. I'm curious if there's a similar approach or optimization I could implement in Python.

Would it be more efficient to use a different data structure or database for this kind of problem?
Given that the data is being updated continuously and recalculations need to be done instantly, is there a better tool or library for managing this kind of workload? For example, would a database like Redis or a framework like Apache Kafka be more suited for real-time data processing?


Example Code:
Here is a basic example of my current implementation using NumPy and functions:
import numpy as np

# Dummy data array for securities
data = np.array([
    [100, 1000, 0, 0],  # Security A
    [150, 2000, 0, 0],  # Security B
    # ... more securities
])

# Example functions for recalculations
def calculate_moving_average(price_array):
    # Simplified moving average calculation
    return np.mean(price_array[-10:])

def calculate_volatility(price_array):
    # Simplified volatility calculation
    return np.std(price_array[-10:])

# Update data and recalculate functions
def update_security(security_index, new_price):
    # Update price
    data[security_index, 0] = new_price
    
    # Add functions to be recalculated for this security
    functions_to_recalculate = [calculate_moving_average, calculate_volatility]
    
    # Loop through functions and recalculate values
    for func in functions_to_recalculate:
        # Example recalculation logic
        result = func(data[security_index, 0])
        print(f'Recalculated value: {result}')

# Simulate an update
update_security(0, 105)


Premature optimization is root of all evil. That being said, if you need you can store results from previous iteration somewhere for further use and calculate only what's needed on new data. Exact solution will depend on type and amount of data.

You can update the function values ​​instead of recalculating them each time, since it is faster. For example, for a window of 10 points, the moving average can be calculated as follows: m_a+=0.1*(value[end]-value[end-10]).
Standard deviation can be calculated in a similar way.

@dankal444 I have implemented this, although it might not be apparent in the question. My question was phrased like that just as a way of phrasing what a more efficient way might be. My implementation (the above) at the moment is lagging behind so just consistently gets more and more out of time

@HarrySpratt 1) if you need only running averages/standard deviations what Alex suggest is a way to go. You will have more efficient code both CPU- and memory-wise. 2) "New data for a security is fed into the corresponding row of the NumPy array" - so you store numpy array somewhere and it increases in size indefinitely? And then use only last 10 values to compute running average?

A couple will be able to utilise this technique such as ones related to historically data where i have the last x trades / data points. Not indefinitely growing. The quoted comment is meant to highlight the data from a source such as Bloomberg such as the current bid / offer price. One that is constantly changing /  being replaced.

For instance if 10 formulas rely on the bid then 10 would have to be recalculated.

Use a circular buffer. This approach still uses pure Numpy, but Pandas is also possible.
import numpy as np

securities = np.array(
    object=[
        ('A', 1000, np.nan, np.nan),
        ('B', 2000, np.nan, np.nan),
    ],
    dtype=[
        ('name', 'U6'),
        ('volume', np.uint64),
        ('moving_average', np.float64),
        ('volatility', np.float64),
    ],
)

n_securities = len(securities)
n_history = 6  # 10
price_write_index = np.zeros(shape=n_securities, dtype=np.int8)
prices = np.full(
    shape=(n_securities, n_history), dtype=np.float64, fill_value=np.nan,
)


def update_security(security_idx: int, price: float) -> None:
    """
    This is only suitable if you ALWAYS get ONE price at a time.
    If you get multiple prices at a time, you need to vectorize.
    """
    write_at = price_write_index[security_idx]
    next_at = (write_at + 1) % n_history
    price_write_index[security_idx] = next_at
    prices[security_idx, write_at] = price

    history = prices[security_idx, :]
    securities['moving_average'][security_idx] = np.nanmean(history)
    securities['volatility'][security_idx] = np.nanstd(history)


rand = np.random.default_rng(seed=0)  # for reproducibility
for _ in range(15):
    update_security(security_idx=1, price=rand.uniform(low=0, high=10))

    # To look at the operation of the circular buffer
    print(prices[1])

[6.36961687        nan        nan        nan        nan        nan]
[6.36961687 2.69786714        nan        nan        nan        nan]
[6.36961687 2.69786714 0.40973524        nan        nan        nan]
[6.36961687 2.69786714 0.40973524 0.16527636        nan        nan]
[6.36961687 2.69786714 0.40973524 0.16527636 8.13270239        nan]
[6.36961687 2.69786714 0.40973524 0.16527636 8.13270239 9.12755577]
[6.06635776 2.69786714 0.40973524 0.16527636 8.13270239 9.12755577]
[6.06635776 7.29496561 0.40973524 0.16527636 8.13270239 9.12755577]
[6.06635776 7.29496561 5.43624991 0.16527636 8.13270239 9.12755577]
[6.06635776 7.29496561 5.43624991 9.35072424 8.13270239 9.12755577]
[6.06635776 7.29496561 5.43624991 9.35072424 8.15853554 9.12755577]
[6.06635776 7.29496561 5.43624991 9.35072424 8.15853554 0.027385  ]
[8.57404277 7.29496561 5.43624991 9.35072424 8.15853554 0.027385  ]
[8.57404277 0.33585575 5.43624991 9.35072424 8.15853554 0.027385  ]
[8.57404277 0.33585575 7.29655446 9.35072424 8.15853554 0.027385  ]

A second, more complex, approach that reduces the update operation from O(n) to O(1) requires that you still maintain a circular buffer, but also maintain a running sum. On each operation, add the new element and subtract the oldest element, then calculate the mean and deviation manually. This would be a greater benefit if the history window becomes much longer, and it's difficult to guess for your situation whether it will help. In other words, even though it will be O(1), the ancillary costs may still be greater than the cost of calls to C-optimized mean()/std().
